# Use Chinese LiPo battery charger units in series (Create a 2s charger)

Tags: pcb, battery-charging, safety, lipo

I have received two LiPo charging modules on eBay with under-voltage and overcharge protection built in.

I would like to achieve a voltage of 7.4V, by connecting the outputs of the two modules in series. I am aware of the many dangers of LiPo batteries and so I am trying to take precaution and make sure that I haven't missed anything.

As far as I can see it will be safe to wire up each of the charging modules with a battery (I am using batteries of the same capacity for each module)

I can then wire up the outputs of the modules in series to achieve the 7.4V output. I can use a single 5V rail to power both modules to allow for simultaneous charging of both batteries. When either of the batteries dies, the circuit will break and thus the over discharge will work normally.

- Have I got anything wrong here?
- Is there anything that I should be
  cautious about when using the modules in series instead of the
  normal, single battery with a single cell?
  [image: Charging modules]

Comment: No you can't. Multi-cell chargers exist for a reason, these are not just a bunch of single-cell chargers glued together. Oh, and bear in mind that posting questions like that in a row will soon lock your account into the "1 question per week" limit.

Comment: Would it be possible to help me understand why you can't? I did know multi-cell charges exist, however it is cheaper to buy single cell chargers and I would also like to find out why it is not possible, so I can learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the image I can see that the `OUT-` and the `IN-` are connected together. This means that if you power them in parallel and wire the output in series you effectively have created a short.

Which means that during charging you have to disconnect the series connector and during use have to disconnect the inputs.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that out! If I use two separate wall chargers to charge the batteries simultaneously, will that isolate the two batteries and prevent a short circuit?

Comment: @JustinWylie if their outputs are ungrounded then yes. Any connector that you can touch must be isolated from mains.